# VSCode - Weird syntax formatting for JavaScript files upon saving

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, save

I noticed something weird going on when hitting ctrl+s in VSCode.

I have some JavaScript here and each time I hit ctrl+s lines 7+8 will get indented. At first I thought it was because of some extension rules (using Beautify for example). So I disabled all my extensions but still the following happens:

[image]

Then I noticed that removing the  tags fixes the auto-formatting issue.
But why is that, any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: That should be good for you if it formats your JS code without any extention.

Comment: What's the filename? `foo.js`? `bar.html`? *(Specifically, the extension.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Then I noticed that removing the tags fixes the auto-formatting issue.

If this is a `.js` file, you shouldn't have HTML in it. The tags shouldn't be there.

Comment: Thanks, that's most likely it. Is there a way to disable auto-formatting on save for single files?

Comment: @colonel_claypoo: I don't know. Why do you want script tags in your `.js` file?

Comment: It's code for a SharePoint webpart and I wanted to be able to write it in VSCode and then simply copy paste it in SharePoint. But 'll just comment out those two tags then. Thanks.

Comment: @colonel_claypoo: Or change the extension to `.html`. :-)